# Locator selenium "classL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote this test code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
start = time.time() #pro zjištění doby testu
for index in range (1):#Pro automatické ověření ve dvou prohlížčích
    if index ==0:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\selenium browser drivers\chromedriver.exe")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\selenium browser drivers\geckodriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://cs.laurie-project.com/login") #načtení stránky
    time.sleep(1) #počkat 1 sekundu
    confirmation = driver.find_element(by="class", value="button primary success-button mr-10")
    confirmation.click() #potvrzení vyskakovacího okna
    login_field = driver.find_element(by="id", value="username-label")
    login_field.send_keys("TestovaciUcet")# Vyplnění uživatelského jména
    password_field = driver.find_element(by="id", value="pw-label")
    password_field.send_keys("Heslo123")#Vyplnění hesla
    login_button = driver.find_element(by="id", value="register-label")
    login_button.click()#Odeslání přihlášení
    if driver.current_url == "https://cs.laurie-project.com/home":
        out_link = driver.find_element(by="link_text", value="/logout")
        out_link.click()#Odhlášení
    else:
        print("Chyba přihlášení")#Chyba přihlášení
end = time.time()
print("Doba trvání testu v sekundách je", end-start)#Výpis doby testu
```

but I got large error message

```
C:\Users\Děti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:\selenium browser drivers\chromedriver.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Děti\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    confirmation = driver.find_element(by="class", value="button primary success-button mr-10")
  File "C:\Users\Děti\PycharmProjects\TestInstitutBiostatistiky\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1248, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Děti\PycharmProjects\TestInstitutBiostatistiky\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Děti\PycharmProjects\TestInstitutBiostatistiky\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
Stacktrace:



Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried change "class" by "class name", "class_name" and "class.name" and use find_element_by_class_name(). Nothing work. Do anybody an idea, what I can try to make this code work? Thanks.

Comment: Please, post a minimum example that raises the exception. There are many lines in your code that are not related to the problem. This will make other people more prone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking to click on this button and it is erring out:  [Confirmation Button snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65pq9.png)

If yes, then this would work:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close reveal']"))).click()
```

You may locate by css selector also, if you may like.

CSS Selector:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='button primary success-button mr-10']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you. There is similar instructions for " out_link = driver.find_element(by="link_text", value="/logout")"?

Comment: Do you have value as `/logout`? Can post the DOM or website link if possible?